When deploying a flutter web app to firebase using firebase deploy can't find eslint config file
I am trying to deploy a flutter web app to firebase using firebase deploy but I keep getting an error. This is the output from the deploy:
(node:5944) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

=== Deploying to 'deal-diligence-5de73'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 9.5.0

ESLint couldn't find an eslint.config.(js|mjs|cjs) file.

From ESLint v9.0.0, the default configuration file is now eslint.config.js.
If you are using a .eslintrc.* file, please follow the migration guide
to update your configuration file to the new format:

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/migration-guide

If you still have problems after following the migration guide, please stop by
https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

This is output from flutter doctor -v:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 761747bfc5 (2 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
• Engine revision edd8546116
• Dart version 3.4.3
• DevTools version 2.34.3
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Nathan.Kane\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.10.3)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.10.35013.160
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0--11609105)
[√] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Nathan.Kane\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.90.0
[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.114
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 126.0.2592.61
[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!
I have tried to find the eslint file but was not able to find it.
Here are the debugging details. If you need more please let me know.
I am working on Windows 11, and VSCode.
I am trying to host this on Firebase.
I have tried a different machine also Windows 11 but I get a lot of dependency errors and running flutter pub upgrade doesn't work.
I hope this helps.
UPDATE
Here is some more from the "output" window in VSCode:
[Info  - 3:04:17 PM] ESLint server is starting.
[Info  - 3:04:21 PM] ESLint server running in node v20.9.0
[Info  - 3:04:21 PM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 3:04:22 PM] ESLint library loaded from: C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Error - 3:04:22 PM] Calculating config file for file:///c%3A/deal_diligence/deal_diligence/firebase.json) failed.
Error: Could not find config file.
    at locateConfigFileToUse (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:349:21)
    at async calculateConfigArray (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:385:49)
    at async ESLint.calculateConfigForFile (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:1171:25)
    at async ESLint.isPathIgnored (C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\node_modules\eslint\lib\eslint\eslint.js:1195:24)
    at async c:\Users\Nathan.Kane\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:24295
    at async Object.M [as withClass] (c:\Users\Nathan.Kane\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:19807)
    at async O.then.m.validate (c:\Users\Nathan.Kane\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:24255)
    at async c:\Users\Nathan.Kane\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:234417
    at async c:\Users\Nathan.Kane\.vscode\extensions\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10\server\out\eslintServer.js:1:63886

So it is not finding the eslint.config file.
UPDATE:
I ran elsint --init and that error went away but now I have other errors.
How can I fix this error?
Thanks

I’m voting to close this question because It was already asked and closed because of lack of debugging details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78652931/trying-to-deploy-web-app-through-firebase-deploy-command-but-it-is-not-finding-e?noredirect=1. @losttexan, please add debugging details to the initial question

@RenaudTarnec, sorry for not adding any debugging information. To be honest, I really don't know how to debug this issue. I added some information to the original post that I hope will be helpful. Please let me know what else I can provide to help in answering this question.
